# How do I enable CORS for a local python3 http.server?

Tags: 20.04, python3

I have a local server running on my Ubuntu using python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1.

Is there a flag I can pass to enable CORS?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found one closer code sample recently.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# It's python3 -m http.server PORT for a CORS world

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import sys


class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
        return super(CORSRequestHandler, self).end_headers()

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

host = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else '0.0.0.0'
port = int(sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8080

print("Listening on {}:{}".format(host, port))
httpd = HTTPServer((host, port), CORSRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Save above content to a file say, `cors_server.py`.

Now you can use this like
`python cors_server.py 8080`

Credits:
https://fpira.com/blog/2020/05/python-http-server-with-cors